# Batch script process a list of two or more parameter sets in a For loop to execute in one line of code

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

```
set listSource=Source_1 Source_2 Source_3
set listDestination=c:\Destination_1 c:\Destination_2 c:\Destination_3

:: Looking for one line like the example below
for /D /R %%A in (%listSource%) AND %%B in (%listDestination%) do ( robocopy %%A %%B)

::Instead of what I have currently...
for /D /R %%A in (Source_1) do robocopy %%A c:\Destination_1
for /D /R %%A in (Source_2) do robocopy %%A c:\Destination_2
for /D /R %%A in (Source_3) do robocopy %%A c:\Destination_3
```

So I would like to replace the **{Source Directory}** and **{Destination Directory}** parameters in *Robocopy* command with **variables** that reference corresponding **list(s)** so Robocopy will populate the variables with each lists **contents** on each pass (**concurrently** as a **set of two** variables). Quite simply, I'm trying to eliminate unnecessary repetition, using one line in place of several to accomplish the same task.

_______**List A** _________**List B**_______

1. *c:\Source1* **>>>** *c:\Destination1*
2. *c:\Source2* **>>>** *c:\Destination2*
3. *c:\Source3* **>>>** *c:\Destination3*

Comment: I know "(set)" in "for loops" can recurse through a list of parameters such as file names. What I'm looking for is the ability to do the same thing in some parameter (concurrently) in the command "Do" section; in this case, the destination parameter in Robocopy.

Comment: You’d need to nest the loops. And is not a word which the loop understands it’s a logical operator

Comment: Thank you Ross! I'll give it a try and let you know if it works. Yea, I knew AND or && is not valid being used in this context. It was just to illustrate logically what I'm trying to do. Thank you again!

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution did not produce the result I was looking for. I need the parameters in (set) to advance in the process concurrently as if they were in the same 'for-loop' thread. Would setting up an array be more appropriate in this case, shift function or function calling 'CALL'?

Answer (score 1):

I feel powershell will work better but I think this is what you are after (I left the echoes in so you can see what it does) but you'll want to edit the line begining with "echo robocopy "

> X.BAT as follows

```
@echo off
set listSource=Source_1~c:\Destination_1 Source_2~c:\Destination_2 Source_3~c:\Destination_3
for %%A in (%listSource%) do ( 
echo %%A
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=~" %%C in ("%%A") do (
echo robocopy %%C %%D
)
)
```

Gives

```
C:\Users\ross>x
Source_1~c:\Destination_1
robocopy Source_1 c:\Destination_1
Source_2~c:\Destination_2
robocopy Source_2 c:\Destination_2
Source_3~c:\Destination_3
robocopy Source_3 c:\Destination_3
```